# Using image colors to draw boundaries on image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to use OpenCV to take an RGB image and identify a boundary or draw a line where the sidewalk meets the grass. Typical methods like canny edge detection and then using hough lines is not extremely helpful since it is easily influenced by other potential lines in the environment.

Let's say I have the RGB image below [RGB sidewalk image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDIyW.jpg), in the image, there is a clear boundary where the sidewalk meets the grass. This boundary becomes even more prominent when you convert into the HSV space and blur the image as shown in [HSV sidewalk image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGRK1.jpg). I believe color segmentation is the best bet I am just not sure how to approach it. Using the code `hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)     green_low = np.array([25 , 0, 50] ) green_high = np.array([75, 255, 255]) curr_mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, green_low, green_high)`
I was able to generate a mask that almost gets me to where I want as shown in this figure [grass mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbPaC.jpg). I just need to use this mask to draw my line without getting mixed up with the other greens detected in the picture.

Comment: It looks to me like you've just about got it. Maybe just a little more fiddling with your HSV range. I can't think of a better way to do it other than using a semantic segmentation AI model.